# Trouble with LearningStats package of R (statistics)

Tags: r, normal-distribution, confidence-interval, variance

I have the following sample of a normal poblation in R

```
x = c(15.6,14.8,14.4,16.6,13.8,14.0,17.3,17.4,18.6,16.2,14.7,15.7,16.4,13.9,14.8,17.5)
```

I'm trying to find a confidence interval for the variance with confidence level 95 %, knowing that the poblational mean is 15.

**This is what I've tried:**

```
mu = 15
n = length(x)
alpha = 0.05                              # Alpha level
S2mu = sum((x - mu)^2)/n                  # Sample estimator of variance
x1 = qchisq(1 - alfa/2, df = n)   
x2 = qchisq(alfa/2, df = n)       
interval_var = c(n*S2mu/x1, n*S2mu/x2)    # Conffidence interval for variance
```

This gives the following result:

```
interval_var = [1.430040, 5.971628]
```

However, using [LearningStats](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) package, specifically using the function [variance.CI](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) I get the following conffidence interval:

```
variance.CI(x, mu = mu, conf.level = 0.95)

 S²μ: 6.64673 units²

           95% confidence interval for the variance of a Normal population with known mean

                                (nS²μ/χ²ₙ,₁₋α̸₂  ,  nS²μ/χ²ₙ,α̸₂)
 
                                       (3.68682 , 15.3956) units²
```

It seems that variance.CI uses the estimator (S2mu)^2 instead of S2mu. Whose result is correct?

Comment: There may not be universal agreement as to the definition of "confidence interval" , but I would start by checking **units** .  You presumably want a value in the same units as your test data has.   if  S^2_mu  has said units, then use that.  Possibly the square of that is the confidence in units of Variance rather than Standard Deviation ?